# Microsoft Ergonomic 4000 not working

Tags: keyboard

I just got a new [Microsoft Ergonomic 4000](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/natural-ergonomic-keyboard-4000/B2M-00012) and it seems to not work out of the box. It doesn't function in Windows or in the BIOS.

Are there any checks I can make before RMAing the keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is the MS Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000. If it doesn't function in the BIOS and your previous keyboard does, RMA it. I have one of these and there is no reason why it should not work out of the box.

Comment: If new hardware doesn't work, it's usually easier to RMA it. The warranty or return policy should still be in effect, and it should be free. It's annoying, but personally, I'd rather they spend the effort fixing it than me, if possible.

Comment: Tried to get it working, was a waste of time. MS warranty is 3 years no questions asked, should've RMAed it as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the batteries
2. Check that it turns on on its own
3. Check with another computer
4. Look at the documentation to see if there are any syncing steps you need to take between the keyboard and its USB dongle

Good luck!